# How to solve the error "Redundant conformance of viewController to protocol UIScrollViewDelegate in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiscrollview

I am new on stackOverflow and learning swift. I am getting the error
 "Redundant conformance of viewController to protocol while working with Stretch headers.UIScrollViewDelegate. I am specifying my code below. please correct any one .

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController , UIScrollViewDelegate {
    private let kTableHeaderHeight : CGFloat = 300.0
    // Using Implicitly Unwrapped Optional, UIView!
    var headerView:UIView!

    let items = [
    NewsItem(category: .World, summary: "Climate Change protests, Need to preserve our Ecosysytem"),
    NewsItem(category: .India, summary: "Climate Change protests, Need to preserve our Ecosysytem"),
    NewsItem(category: .America, summary: "Climate Change protests,Need to preserve our Ecosysytem"),
    NewsItem(category: .Japan, summary: "Climate Change protests, Need to preserve our Ecosysytem"),
    NewsItem(category: .China, summary: "Climate Change protests, Need to preserve our Ecosysytem"),
    NewsItem(category: .Nepal, summary: "Climate Change protests, Need to preserve our Ecosysytem")]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        headerView = tableView.tableHeaderView
        tableView.tableHeaderView = nil
        tableView.addSubview(headerView)
   tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(kTableHeaderHeight, 0, 0, 0)
        tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, -kTableHeaderHeight)
        updateHeaderView()
    }
    func updateHeaderView(){
        var HeaderRect = CGRectMake(0,-kTableHeaderHeight, tableView.bounds.width, kTableHeaderHeight)

        if tableView.contentOffset.y < -kTableHeaderHeight{
            HeaderRect.origin.y = tableView.contentOffset.y
            HeaderRect.size.height = -tableView.contentOffset.y
        }
        headerView.frame = HeaderRect
    }
    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {enter code here
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()   
    }
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        updateHeaderView()
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let item = items[indexPath.row]
let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell" forIndexPath: indexPath) as! NewsItemTableViewCell
        cell.newsItem = item
 return cell          
    }
```

Answer (score 21):

You are getting this error because your class `ViewController` conforming to the protocol `UIScrollViewDelegate` in two ways. `UITableViewController` is already conforming to that protocol, you dont need to add it again. So remove `UIScrollViewDelegate`from there, you are good.

This is how it is `UITableViewController` conforms to  `UITableViewDelegate` which conforms to `UIScrollViewDelegate`. This would be enough

```
class ViewController: UITableViewController{
}
```

Comment: Thanks you very much

Comment: Worked for me too!! Thanks, btw it is also given in the firebase sample code  [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/tree/master/messaging)

Answer (score 5):

The shortest explanation would be that Your UITableViewController comes with a built in scroll View, so you ***don't*** need a delegate for Scrollview. Remove `UIScrollViewDelegate`  and you will be fine.

Feel free to ask any question :)

Answer (score 0):

Its tell about protocol confirmed/added more than one time.

By mistake I have added `UITableViewDataSource` two times.
[In my case I was using `UITableView`]